# gradle plugin dependencies not found under buildSrc

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a working `build.gradle` that I'd like to refactor into the buildSrc directory but I'm having trouble finding the dependencies.

**Working build.gradle:**

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2'
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'groovy'
}

group "com.example"
version "0.0.1"

class Foo  {
  Foo() {
    new HTTPBuilder('http://www.example.com')
  }
}
```

**Non-working refactored build.gradle:**

However, when I try to split into the following:

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2'
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'groovy'
}

group "com.example"
version "0.0.1"
```

and `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/Foo.groovy`

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

class Foo  {
  Foo() {
    new HTTPBuilder('http://www.example.com')
  }
}
```

Gives the error:

> ```
> C:\Project\buildSrc\src\main\groovy\Foo.groovy: 7: unable to resolve
> class HTTPBuilder  @ line 5, column 26.
>        HTTPBuilder client = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.example.com')
> ```

How can I get gradle to recognise the dependencies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a `build.gradle` file for `buildSrc` directory. Try this:

`C:\Project\buildSrc\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2'
}
```

There is more details in [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources) documentation section.

Comment: I tried everything except "appy plugin: 'groovy'". Many thanks!